# Можно ли установить MS SQL 2012 Express отображая только окно лицензии

Tags: sql-server, cmd, install

Возникла такая задача, я использую Wix installer, для установки приложения, в комплекте которого идет MS SQL Express 2012, для того, чтобы установить SQL Server 2012 Express Edition, я использую следующие параметры командной стоки:

```
/ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLExpress
/FEATURES=SQLEngine,FullText,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,Conn,SNAC_SDK 
/SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=Pa$$w0rd /TCPENABLED=1 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
/SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Manual /UpdateEnabled=False 
/SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=TRUE
/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /QS
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы пользователь подтвердил только согласие с лицензионным соглашением, а остальное будет устанавливаться автоматом. Можно ли так сделать и как?

Comment: Параметры описываются тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259(v=sql.110).aspx. Согласно документу, описываемой тобой возможности нет.

Comment: @Akina ладно, спасибо, буду делать свое окно в WIx